# Can i store requests scope data on thread-local even with non-blocking connectors?

Tags: jakarta-ee, tomcat, thread-local

I am using a ThreadLocal object to store authentication information om my restful API (sessionless). In a Filter i retrieve my authentication headers and set the user details (name, roles, etc) in a thread local variable, used in the request processing authorization.

Can i rely on a ThreadLocal variable to store request scoped information regardless of the container and connector thread management?

Answer (score 0):

Based on my understanding of the spec, you can't count on that. At least, it won't be portable.

I opened this to ask for clarification: https://java.net/jira/browse/JAVAEE_SPEC-39

> My interpretation from EJB3.2/§16.2.2 is that you can't have
>   ThreadLocal's, the main reason being that thread management is not
>   portable across server implementations. As we know, there are no
>   guarantees on threads, so it's not reliable at best, and probably
>   dangerous.
>
> From this, ThreadLocal usage can't be portable.
>   Introduction of §16.2.2 says this:
>
> "This section describes the
>   programming restrictions that a Bean Provider must follow to ensure
>   that the  enterprise bean is portable and can be deployed in any
>   compliant EJB container. The restrictions apply  to the implementation
>   of the business methods. Section 16.3, which describes the container's
>   view of  these restrictions, defines the programming environment that
>   all EJB containers must provide."